# Парсинг таблицы с Simple html dom

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Всем доброго времени суток
Использую парсера Simple html dom, для парсинга.

Есть такая таблица:

```
<tr>
<td class="b-product-info__cell">Производитель <span class="icon-help" id="product-attribute-0-0">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td class="b-product-info__cell">WS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="b-product-info__cell">Страна производитель</td>
<td class="b-product-info__cell">Китай</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="b-product-info__cell">Тип туристической мебели</td>
<td class="b-product-info__cell">Стул со спинкой и подлокотниками</td>
</tr>
```

Ее я прохожу через такой код:

```
$spans = $h->find('td.b-product-info__cell');
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    if ($span->plaintext == 'Производитель') {
    $name = $span->nextSibling('.b-product-info__cell')->plaintext;
    echo $name;
}
}
```

Собственно Производитель меняю на названия других ячеек все работает нормально.

все строки парсятся нормально за исключением вот этой:

```
<td class="b-product-info__cell">Производитель <span class="icon-help" id="product-attribute-0-0">&nbsp;</span></td>
```

если я все правильно понял наличие в td

```
<span class="icon-help" id="product-attribute-0-0">&nbsp;</span>
```

не дает найти значение в

```
<td class="b-product-info__cell">WS</td>
```

а именно WS

Подскажите как мне проскочить / исключить этот блок. Возможно его можно удалить через outertext

Спасибо

Comment: Может `$span->plaintext` перед `if ($span->plaintext == 'Производитель')` сделать `$plaintext = trim(str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $span->plaintext))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$spans = $html->find('td.b-product-info__cell');
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    $name = trim(str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $span->plaintext));
    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы. В общем такой код заработал так как мне нужно.

```
$spans = $h->find('td.b-product-info__cell');
foreach ($spans as $span) {
if (stristr($span->plaintext, 'Назначение') !== FALSE) {
    $name = $span->nextSibling('.b-product-info__cell')->plaintext;
    echo $name;
}
}
```